# Is it normal to use LocalDb in production?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, localdb

I know that using `LocalDb` is very good and easy for developement, I wonder if it's good idea to use it in production when I host websites on IIS server?

I'm asking because I wonder if it won't have any kind of speed issues in production.

This is my connection string that I want to use in production

```
Server=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|ProjectDB.mdf;
```

Comment: Why? Why? Why? Use a proper instance of SQL Server Express and make all of your users connect to the same, common instance of your database. In the current mode, won't each connection fire up its own copy of the database, and it will get discarded once it's done? Never mind that the security context won't work correctly here AFAIK, and that you will likely be violating EULA. Also why on earth are you using MultipleActiveResultSets? Is that on purpose?

Comment: No, LocalDB is not meant for production.

Comment: @AaronBertrand because I had `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first` error.

Comment: @Hossein
This behavior can be modified
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153509/how-to-prevent-sql-server-localdb-auto-shutdown

Comment: @RemusRusanu. Can you show some data from Microsoft on why LocalDB cannot be used in production? It would be helpfull

Answer (score 48, accepted):

LocalDB is absolutely supported in production. From the performance point of view it is identical to SQL Server Express, as they share the same database engine.

Now, for a site running in full IIS I would recommend using service-based instance of SQL Server Express. Since IIS is running as a service it is best to have a service-hosted database as well. That means you should **not** be using `User Instance=true` or `AttachDbFileName=...` in your connection string.

If you want to learn more, I recommend this [post on using LocalDB from full IIS, part 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlexpress/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile) and [its follow up, part 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlexpress/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership). They go into more details.

Comment: not sure how to make it work in Server 2012, the file applicationHost.config doesn't show asp.net 4.5 add name entry after installing asp.net.

Comment: LocalDB is absolutely not supported in production.

Comment: What makes you say so @HosseinShahdoost? Did Microsoft reverse its production support? A link might be useful if so.

Comment: This is the first sentence of Microsoft's Documentations
"Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDB is an execution mode of SQL Server Express targeted to program developers", https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx
Also this Msdn blog has a lot of useful stuff to read. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/02/26/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition.aspx

Comment: I don't see how this is a statement that LocalDB is "absolutely not supported in production". It was created to make developers' life easier, which include the embedded database scenarios (but not in-process). Using it with IIS is a stretch, which I've pointed out in my answer.

Comment: I don't see how this is a statement that LocalDb is "absolutely supported in production" as well. Not to run the main app's db. By taking a good look at the interface you can see that It was created to help developers run their integration and system tests easier.

Comment: LocalDB is the .net alternative for SqlLite ( no permissions required), so i think the same statements is appropriate for LocalDB : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913067/sqlite-as-a-production-database-for-a-low-traffic-site considering the use-case.

You can use it in production, but consider it only for low traffic stuff

Comment: @KrzysztofKozielczyk i use localdb in desktop application. instance was shut down automatically. could you resolve this problem?

Comment: @amir110, by default, LocalDB instances shut down after 5 minutes of no activity.    The instance will start again automatically upon the next connection *by its owner/creator* to one of its databases. Conversely, it will *not* start automatically if the user connecting is not the owner/creator (in the case of shared instances.)
If this comment doesn't help you solve your problem, post a new question with more detail, and include a link to the new question in a comment here, so we will be notified.

Answer (score 19):

"Normal" - hard to say, that's a relative term.

Permitted - yes.  [Here is a quote](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-an-improved-sql-express/)  from the Microsoft SQL Server Express blog where LocalDB was introduced:

*"...if the simplicity (and limitations) of LocalDB fit the needs of the target application environment, developers **can continue using it in production, as LocalDB makes a pretty good embedded database too.**"*

---

UPDATE (March 2019)

After using LocalDB in dozens of production sites for two solid years now, I'll confirm that it works. However, **if you need a free multi-user** ("shared" in LocalDB terminology) **DB, use SQL Server Express instead**. LocalDB is not a good multi-user solution. There are MANY obstacles to overcome. I don't have time now, but if you would like details on those obstacles and respective workarounds, leave a comment, and I'll document them here or in another question.

---

UPDATE (April 2021)

*Showstopper* -- the shared (i.e., multi-user) instance feature is broken in SQL Server LocalDB 2017 and 2019. Having one of those versions *installed* will even prevent accessing a shared instance created in an *earlier* version. The problem is [documented here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249097/cant-connect-to-sql-server-2017-local-db-shared-instance). The only known "workaround" is to uninstall the broken LocalDB versions, and use LocalDB 2016 or earlier.

---

UPDATE (September 2021)

There is now [a fix for the *Showstopper* issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/294928) mentioned in the preceding update (UPDATE April 2021). **I have successfully tested this fix for both versions.** Minimum versions are:

- 14.0.3391.2, delivered in [SQL Server 2017 Cumulative Update 24](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5001228-cumulative-update-24-for-sql-server-2017-fc49353e-cbb6-4862-9178-c319ce6f9db4)
- 15.0.4138.2, delivered in [SQL Server 2019 Cumulative Update 11](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5003249-cumulative-update-11-for-sql-server-2019-657b2977-a0f1-4e1f-8b93-8c2ca8b6bef5)

Comment: Could you briefly describe the obstacles you run into?

Comment: If you only need single-user access, you should be fine. Isssues arise when you want the DB to be multi-user, because the process hosting the instance is shut down when the instance creator logs off, and can only be re-started by the creator. Thus you need an "always on" user as the creator. If you can create a dedicated service account, do that. It wasn't an option for me. I chose "Local System" but that presents other issues, some of which are documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50491641/1633949. You also need to impersonate that account when you initially setup instance security.

Comment: There were other obstacles as well, let me know if the ones above don't dissuade you, and I'll note the others too.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think so,

Even though LocalDb and SQLExpress might be the same on performance, LocalDb's Process shuts down itself if it doesn't have any request for a while. And usually the next request takes too long to response (or even worse, it times out).

I would recommend you install your own instance of SQLEXPRESS.