# How to prevent SQL Server LocalDB auto shutdown?

Tags: sql-server, localdb

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB. Instances seem to stop automatically after 10 minutes if there is no activity on them. Is there a clean way to keep an instance running forever?

Answer (score 34):

The timeout is configurable via T-SQL with `'user instance timeout'` option:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'user instance timeout', 5;
GO
```

The timeout is expressed in **minutes** and has a maximum value of `65535`. I'm pretty sure you need to restart the instance after setting it. And don't try setting it to `0`, it will just make the instance shut down immediately after starting, which will make it hard to set the value back to something useful :-).

Source: [this BOL article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684.aspx) containing other useful information on User Instances that are applicable to LocalDB instances as well.

**Final Remark**

If you need something that's always running and starts whenever a computer starts you might just consider using regular, service-based, instance of SQL Server Express.

Comment: Note that minimum value for timeout option is 5 so it is not possible to set timeout value below 5 minutes.

Answer (score 18):

Here is how to do Krzysztof Kozielczyk's answer from the command line.

Start the `localdb` instance.

```
C:\> sqllocaldb start v11.0
LocalDB instance "v11.0" started.
```

Get the server path, which is the Instance pipe name.

```
C:\> sqllocaldb info v11.0
Name:               v11.0
Version:            11.0.3000.0
Shared name:        IIS_DB
Owner:              DESKTOP-AAAT5QS\bigfo
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Running
Last start time:    2/17/2016 12:06:43 PM
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#SH9D87FB\tsql\query
```

Run an SQL command on that server.

```
C:\> sqlcmd -S np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#SH9D87FB\tsql\query

1> sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
2> GO

Configuration option 'show advanced options' changed from 1 to 1. 
Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.

1> RECONFIGURE;
2> GO

1> sp_configure 'user instance timeout', 5;
2> GO

Configuration option 'user instance timeout' changed from 5 to 5. 
Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.

1> RECONFIGURE;
2> GO

> exit
```

Comment: i didnt have name pipe so i used this **sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB"**

Comment: To see the current setting, it is `sp_configure 'user instance timeout'`