# How to connect to SQL Server LocalDB using Invoke-Sqlcmd?

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012, localdb, sqlps

I have `sqlcmd.exe` from both SQLServer 2008 and SQLServer 2012:

```
PS C:\> Get-Command sqlcmd.exe

Definition
----------
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE
```

By modifying `$env:PATH` i force the use of `sqlcmd.exe` from SQL Server 2012:

```
PS C:\> $env:PATH = ($env:PATH -split ";" | Where-Object { $_ -notlike "*\Microsoft SQL Server\100\*" }) -join ";"
PS C:\> Get-Command sqlcmd.exe

Definition
----------
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE
```

The default instance of LocalDB is up and running, and owned by the current user:

```
PS C:\> sqllocaldb i v11.0
Name:               v11.0
Version:            11.0.2318.0
Shared name:
Owner:              DOMAIN\me
Auto-create:        Yes
State:              Running
Last start time:    12/06/13 18:17:57
Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#08EDBEF0\tsql\query
```

Now, i can execute command on `(localdb)\v11.0` using `sqlcmd.exe`

```
PS C:\> sqlcmd.exe -S "(localdb)\v11.0" -Q "select 1"

-----------
          1
```

But when trying the same with `Invoke-Sqlcmd` i get a connection error:

```
PS C:\> Import-Module sqlps
PS C:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "(localdb)\v11.0" -Query "select 1"
Invoke-Sqlcmd : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

What can i do to lmake `Invoke-Sqlcmd` connect to `(localdb)\v11.0` ?

Comment: Interestingly enough, it works from PowerGUI and fails from powershell. I traced both processes with ProcessMonitor and both load the correct module (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\SQLPS\SQLPS.PSD1). Both are able to connect to a "regular" instance, such as SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: Do you have the correct execution policy for this? I recommend changing the execution policy to ByPass or Unrestricted.


`Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as the preferred solution.

Comment: Wow, the OP and upvoters of the question are a very particular crowd.  The highest-rated answers here (at the time I'm writing this) have zero votes and it goes down from there.  I think it would be constructive to hear what people have tried and what's not working for them.  The solution I posted (admittedly for an edge case) has been working for me for the better part of a decade, through many updates to PowerShell, SQL Server and Windows.  Is it really true that nothing works for the people who have upvoted this question?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE

[`Invoke-Sqlcmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps) from the [`SqlServer`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/) module supports LocalDB:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "(localdb)\v11.0" -Query "select 1"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ConnectionString "Server=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True" -Query "select 1"

# both will work
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I know `sqlcmd.exe` uses a connection string that has all the information, whereas `Invoke-Sqlcmd` breaks that information down into different parameters. So you likely need to split `(localdb)` and `v11.0` across `ServerInstance`, `Database`, and `ComputerName`. Or you can use the `ConnectionString` parameter instead.

Now, I am not familiar with your use of `localdb` so there might be something funky with the way it handles that...or something.

Answer (score 0):

Got this from a couple other sources, seems to work so far.

[JBs Powershell](http://mspowershell.blogspot.com/2012/07/sql-server-2012-localdb.html)

and

[How can I run PowerShell with the .NET 4 runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094694/how-can-i-run-powershell-with-the-net-4-runtime)

Another way of making PowerShell and LocalDB play nice is to make PowerShell aware of DOTNET 4.0.3. This can be done by creating a file called "powershell.exe.config" in the  C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0 . The file should contain the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration> 
     <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true"> 
          <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319"/> 
          <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/> 
     </startup> 
</configuration>
```

Be aware that this not an officially supported way of using PowerShell, so it might break other stuff ...

Answer (score -1):

I have been doing this at work recently and had some initial troubles connecting to a local Database. To get it to work, I ran the following code;

```
C:\> Import-Module sqlps -DisableNameChecking
SQLSERVER\:> cd ".\SQL\$(hostname)"
SQLSERVER\:> Invoke-Sqlcmd -Username "user" -Password "pass" -Database "databasename" -Query "foobar"
```

This worked for me and I was able to query the database. Obviously, change the Username, Password and Database parameter details to whatever the name of your database on the SQL Instance is called.

Comment: FWIW, this is a local database and not 'localdb' (ie: one is a full sql install and the other is, well, localdb).

Answer (score -1):

This is code that works for me under adverse conditions (see my comments just after the code).  I suspect that simpler code may work in a more common environment, but I haven't dug into it.

The instance pipe times out after a few minutes.  You're better off if you can connect using (localdb)\*instanceName*, because those connections don't seem to time out.

```
function Get-InstancePipeName ([string] $localDbName)
{
  while (!($pipeName = ((sqllocaldb info $localDbName) -match 'instance pipe name').Split(':', 2)[1].Trim()))
  {
    sqllocaldb start $localDbName | Out-Null
  }
  return $pipeName
}

$scsb   = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
$scsb.psbase.DataSource = Get-InstancePipeName localDbName # <== put your db name here
$sc     = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $scsb.ConnectionString

$smoSc  = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection $sc
$smoSvr = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $smoSc
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $smoSvr -Query 'select 1'
```

For reasons currently outside my control, the execution environment where this runs is unusual.  It's a remote execution environment with an incomplete session context.  Also, I had to redefine USERPROFILE to work around some other issues.

[later edit: I recently found [a way to extend the timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14162514/876993) - I had to add a RECONFIGURE after the 2nd sp_configure and (as recommended) stop and start the localdb to get it to take effect)]

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing that invoke-sqlcmd doesn't know what "(localdb)" is.  Try using localhost instead.

Comment: doesn't work for me. Must be something else, but don't know what.

Comment: It would appear that invoke-sqlcmd doesn't support localdb. You have to understand that invoke-sqlcmd isn't just calling sqlcmd and passing in parameters. It is it's own version of sqlcmd and it doesn't fully support everything that sqlcmd does. At least not yet.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLDavis, I understand that it's a whole different version. Yet I don't understand why it works from PowerGUI and fails from powershell.

Comment: PowerGUI may be doing something with the command before actually running it.  It all depends on how they are actually running the PowerShell commands.