# Is there an one-liner to create LocalDB database (not instance) in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, localdb

I want to create a LocalDB database in a way that MDF and LDF files stay on script execution folder.

- I know that we can easily do command substitutions with `$` operator in PowerShell, so, if I state something like `$pwd` it will make a substitution with the output of `pwd` command.
- From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41352807/1475630), I know that `Invoke-SqlCmd` is not a straightforward way of doing things with LocalDB instances.
- I want to execute the following command through PowerShell. How could I accomplish that?

  ```
  sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB" -Q "
  CREATE DATABASE [Test] ON PRIMARY ( 
          NAME = N'Test', 
          FILENAME = N'<$pwd output here>\Test.mdf'
  ) 
  LOG ON ( 
          NAME = N'Test_log', 
          FILENAME = N'<$pwd output here>\Test_log.ldf'
  )"
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a lot more than you are asking, but it will solve your issue.

This will ask you if you want to restore from a template if no then it will create an empty database.

```
$backupFilePath=''
$TempDB=''
$TempDBlog=''
$DBName=''
$Logfilepath=''
$Datafilepath=''

$confirmation = Read-Host "Do you want to use a DB template? [y/n]"

If($confirmation.ToUpper().StartsWith("Y") )
{
$dbCommand = "use [master];RESTORE DATABASE [$DBName] " + "FROM DISK = N'$backupFilePath'" + "WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10, " + "move '$TempDB' to '$Datafilepath" + "\" + "$DBName" + ".mdf', " + "move '$TempDBlog' to '$Logfilepath" + "\" + "$DBName" + ".ldf';" + "alter database [$DBName] modify file (name=N'$TempDB ', newname=N'$DBName" + "_data1');" + "alter database [$DBName] modify file (name=N'$TempDBlog', newname=N'$DBName" + "_log1');" + "alter database [$DBName] set read_committed_snapshot on with rollback immediate;" + "alter database [$DBName] set COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100;"
}

else {
$dbCommand = "use [master];CREATE DATABASE [$DBName] ON " + "( NAME='$DBName" + "_data1', FILENAME='$Datafilepath" + "\" + "$DBName" + "_data1.mdf', SIZE=1GB, MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH=200MB)" + "LOG ON ( NAME='$DBName" + "_log1', FILENAME='$Logfilepath" + "\" + "$DBName" + "_log1.ldf', SIZE=1GB, MAXSIZE=UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH=200MB); " + "alter database [$DBName] set read_committed_snapshot on with rollback immediate;" + "alter database [$DBName] set COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100; " + "set AUTO_CLOSE OFF;"
}
```

Someone will have to edit this into nice looking code break, because it is not allowing me to do it.