# Cannot connect to Microsoft SQL Server using IntelliJ/Rider

Tags: sql-server, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm getting the following error when I try to create a database for my project:

> [08S01] The TCP/IP connection to the host myhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection timed out: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."

I've tried every possible solution I could find online. I changed the ports in the configuration manager to 1433, checked if the port is blocked by the firewall (it's not), turned on the SQL Server Browse, tried using `integratedSecurity = true` int the connection string and nothing worked.

Would appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: Can you connect with SSMS?  Open up SQL Server Configuration Manager.  Is TCP/IP enabled?  Is it bound to an interface?  Can you connect with, for example, Powershell?  Are you specifying the correct instance name?  SQL Server Express Edition doesn't install to the default instance.

Comment: It works fine in SSMS, it listens to the port and I'm using the right instance name. TCP/IP is enabled. It is not bound to any thing because it's new and empty.

Comment: Did you perform all recommendations given in [this post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2016/06/21/connecting-datagrip-to-ms-sql-server/)? Specifically those around enabling TCP/IP connections in SSCM and restarting the server just in case? )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most probable cause of connection failure is explained in the 3rd comment (by Jura Gorohovsky) on the question and is actually covered in the OP.  To repeat, the details are [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2016/06/21/connecting-datagrip-to-ms-sql-server/).

My problem was different and caused by confusion about (localdb).  But before that, as this is the first actual answer, I will summarise the steps in the Jetbrains post, referred to by Jura and address the most common issue.

SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) requires TCP/IP to be enabled for access by Rider (and presumably other Jetbrains products such as Intellij and, in fact any process using JDBC).  The following steps are required:

Configuring SQL Server for Rider connections:

1. Open SQL Server Configuration Manager for the approrpiate version - `cmd.exe /c start C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager14.msc` - SS2017, SQLServerManager13.msc - SS2016, SQLServerManager12.msc - SS2014.  The snap-ins are also found in System32.
2. The detail panel for *SQL Server Services* should show *SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)*.
3. for *SQL Server Network Configuration->Protocols for SQLEXPrESS* ensure that the detail panel shows the line *TCP/IP* as *Enabled*.
4. In *TCP/IP->Properties->IP Addresses* (right click *TCP/IP*).  Set *IPAll->TCP Dynamic Ports* to blank and *IPAll->TCP Port* to 1433 (or other if you have changed the SS config).
5. Confirm all and restart SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) (right click on *SQL Server Services*->*SQL Server (SQLEXPrESS)*) and you should be able to connect with the url `jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost;instance=SQLEXPRESS`.  You can also use the Tds driver.

I assme there is nothing special about SQLEXPRESS and any SS instance you have created can be opened up in the same way.

Note that you may encounter problems if you use a port other than the default of 1433.  (I can't currently find the docs.)  If you specify the port number in the Rider connection page then the instance will be ignored and connection will be made to the default instance.  The instance that you connect to from Rider must be either set as the default or have a port number of 1433.

My problem:
I enabled TCP/IP early on but ran into the problem that I could only connect to some sort of default instance which I know nothing about.  This was caused by my failing to distinguish sufficiently between (localdb) and SQL Server proper, not being sure whether SQLEXPRESS was a separate product or an instance of SS and being unfamiliar with the SS Configuration snap-in.  This will also present itself to the unwary as simply being unable to connect - if you don't happen to have SQLEXPRESS or other SS installed.

[This InfoQ article](https://www.infoq.com/news/2011/07/LocalDB) summarises the role of (localdb). It's a kind of light weight version of SQL server but with none of its process admin and not using the same discoverability or transport.  It will not show up in the SS Configuration snap-in.

Once you have taken on board the distinction between (localdb)/SQLLocalDB.exe and the other flavours of SS such as SQLEXPRESS the connection from Rider is quite simple and covered [here](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000505590-PSA-How-to-set-up-a-LocalDB-data-source-in-Rider).

Connectiong Rider to (localdb) - summary of post referred to above:

1. Run `SQLLocalDB -s MSSQLLocalDB`
2. In Rider right hand panel do *Database->+->Data Source->SQL Server*.
3. Select Driver as *SQL Server (Tds)*
4. Select *LocalDB* from the dropdown to the right of the URL.
5. Select *MSSQLLocalDB* (or other available instance) from the Instance drop down.
6. Optionally specify a database in the text box.
7. Provide credentials if not using pass through authentication
8. Do *Test Connection* etc.

The transport is a named pipe.  The other end is provided by the SQLLocalDB.exe process.  If Rider remains unconnected for more than a few minutes then SQLLocalDB.exe will exit and you will need to rerun it next time you use Rider.  This can be addressed with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153509/how-to-prevent-sql-server-localdb-auto-shutdown).

Tested with Rider 2018.2.3.

Comment: There is a tutorial about localdb as well https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2016/10/07/connecting-datagrip-to-sql-server-express-localdb/

Comment: impressive description... bless