# Connection small SQL Server (LocalDB) C# application always times out the first time it is run. What could cause this?

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

As an exercise, I've been trying to build the database application described in the first chapter of an earlier edition (the 2nd) of *Head First C#*. ([Chapter 1 on O'Reilly website](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/head-first-c/9780596514822/ch01.html)).

I've had to make some modifications because said book is rather ancient, but now it works. It has a SQL Server (`LocalDB`) database, `ContactDB.mdf`, containing only one table, `People`.

[image: Definition of People table]

The only thing is, every time I run the exe for the first time (after starting up Windows), I get a `SqlException` mentioning a time-out. The message is in Dutch, and I would put the English equivalent of it here if I could find it. But despite the same error number, the messages I encounter on the web are different. The message I get refers to a handshake (again, sorry for the language):

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Connection timeout exceeded. The timeout period has elapsed when attempting to use the pre-login handshake confirmation. A possible cause is that the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond in time. The time spent trying to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login]-initialization=16271; handshake=0;

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Request timed out

If I close the application and start it a second time, I don't get the error.

Doing some research, I find that possible causes for a time-out can be a query that takes a long time (my `People` table contains 6 rows) or a firewall issue. Can it be a firewall problem if the application always runs fine the second and subsequent times?

Or should I set a different time-out value?

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: All content of a question must be in English, that includes errors.

Comment: maybe the system simply takes that long to open the DBF and be in a queryable state with a usable  SQL Server engine instance?

Comment: @Larnu It's a drag that messages are not in English anyway. I will try to get rid of the language packs responsible for this behaviour and report back.

Comment: @Marc Gravell I suppose I could adjust the time-out, but I wonder if that is good practice? What if I installed this on someone else's (slower) PC, wouldn't I run the risk of encountering time-outs again? Or would it be best to catch the exception? I'm really a novice at SQL Server, so I have no idea how to go about this.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server Express or LocalDB?

Comment: @Charlieface Oops. Contrary to what I wrote in my original post, I now think that this is LocalDB. At least the connection string at least is "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\users\<userpath>\sources\repos\Contacts\ContactDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True". I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: LocalDB does take a little bit of time to load, so it can occasionally cause timeouts, [you may want to prevent auto-shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153509/how-to-prevent-sql-server-localdb-auto-shutdown). Also [`AttachDbFilename` is a very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename)

Comment: @Charlieface I'll look into the auto-shutdown (or the prevention of it). I didn't like the idea of that hard-coded connection string (which honestly is just the result of clicking some controls and adding some properties), so thanks for pointing me in the right direction.