# Cannot open database aspnet requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user IIS APPPOOL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, localdb, windows-server-2016

I'm getting this error trying to access the local SQL DB for entity framework.
Would be grateful for any tip that could help.

Production server: ASPNET Core 7 web application on IIS 10, Windows server 2016.
Physical machine.

Developing on VS 2022.
Running also SQL express on the same server, accessing from the same application.

The Windows AppPool user can access SQL express, but can't access the database in (localdb)\mssqllocaldb (the error message says "can't open database", i.e. the login works).

I've run this on my development machine, created the EF database and everything works.
Deployed to the server, and the IIS worker can't seem to access the EF database.

I can log into both with the SQL management studio 18, both on the production server and the development machine. The login/user and permissions seem appropriate.

Connection string:

```
Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=aspnet;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;
```

In program.cs I have this code line, a few lines before app.run():

```
if (await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(sUserEmail) == null)
```

which triggers an EF database query.
This line is where the exception in the subject is thrown (full exception text below).

Steps I've taken so far (that didn't make a difference)

1. Renamed the database to something simple with only small and capital letters
2. Changed the database username to something simple (instead of IIS APPPOOL...)
3. Confirmed permissions in the database, for the login and for the user
4. In IIS, modified the application host configuration setting to Windows Authentication enabled (even though for SQL express it's already working)
5. Added permissions of IIS APPPOOL\ user to the database file and folder
6. Dropped the EF database and recreated it with Update-Database
7. Repeated all the operations with Administrator run SQL management studio and Visual Studio
8. Enabled the EnableRetryOnFailure (just for the heck of it)

I've been reading up on custom storage for Identity.
Basically my next step is to try and recreate the database in SQL express, and modify the connection string to point there and try that. I would've actually preferred just one SQL instance for everything so if that works might be even better for me.

But I would love to know and remove the obstacle that's preventing the database connection.
For clarification, I did not write the full names of the database and the App Pool user here.

Please let me know if there's any other info I can provide that could help with this.

Exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure' to the 'UseSqlServer' call.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "aspnet" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\'.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ClientConnectionId:1a0e38a7-1bee-4d50-b1f4-2a10fdd3e7aa
Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698286/login-failed-for-user-iis-apppool-asp-net-v4-0

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that question. In my case the exception indicates that the login itself worked but access to the specific database failed

Comment: From your connection string, I don’t see a username. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes - Trusted_Connection=True; basically Windows authentication would be used.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry - I misunderstood. It must be something to do with those IIS settings. I’ll take a look at my staging setup and see if I can find anything else. Hopefully someone provides an answer in the meantime.

Comment: Check your site's application pool name.  By default it will be "DefaultAppPool".  Your error message states "Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\".  Which is missing the name of the app pool your application is running as.  I'd expect to see something like "Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" there.  Also make sure that connection string is correct... In SQL Management Studio, expand the "Databases" section and be sure you use the full DB name listed there.

Comment: ...and of course, add permissions for IIS APPPOOL\Your-App-Pool's Name to the DB.

Comment: Thanks @pcalkins, that wasn't it. As mentioned in the post, I omitted the actual IIS pool name and the database name on purpose.

Comment: @Alex thanks very much for the support, I appreciate it. I was able to figure out the issue - I had to share mssqllocaldb in order for IIS to be able to access it. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost 2 weeks of being stuck on this, finally found the following read on the SQL local DB:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2016#permissions

> By default, access to the instance of LocalDB is limited to its owner. The data contained in the LocalDB is protected by file system access to the database files. If user database files are stored in a shared location, the database can be opened by anyone with file system access to that location, by using an instance of LocalDB that they own. If the database files are in a protected location, such as the users data folder, only that user, and any administrators with access to that folder, can open the database.

And-

> To connect to a shared instance of LocalDB, add .\ (backslash + dot + backslash) to the connection string to reference the namespace reserved for shared instances. For example, to connect to a shared instance of LocalDB named AppData use a connection string such as (localdb).\AppData as part of the connection string. A user connecting to a shared instance of LocalDB that they don't own must have a Windows Authentication or SQL Server Authentication login.

So as it turns out, when the IIS APPPOOL worker ran the web application, it was loading its own copy of mssqllocaldb which didn't have the EF Identity database  and tables.

To work with mssqllocaldb, I did the following:

1. Obtained info on the mssqllocaldb instance where the EF database is installed, by running via command prompt: sqllocaldb i mssqllocaldb
2. Shared the instance of my user via command prompt: sqllocaldb h "MSSQLLOCALDB" "new shared name"
3. Connected to the shared database in Visual Studio
4. Copied the connection string from the properties of that connection to appsettings.json
5. Ran again Update-Database in the NuGet Package Manager Console
6. Gave the IIS worker file-system access to the folder and contents where the actual files that make up mssqllocaldb reside.
7. Confirmed permissions in the database for the IIS worker login and user via SQL management studio

And then everything just worked normally, all the Identity functionality works!

Comment: By the way, looks like mssqllocaldb times out and the instance stops, and doesn't automatically start.
I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153509/how-to-prevent-sql-server-localdb-auto-shutdown) as a possible solution, but decided to switch to my sqlexpress install for everything and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to look at:

1. Replicate the production configuration on your local machine. Set up IIS to mirror your production server and access your localhost app with IIS...this should make troubleshooting much easier.
2. Remove the untrusted connection string and use a fully defined user / password instead: `<add name={name} connectionString="Data Source={server_name};Initial Catalog={database_name};MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Id={user};Password={password}" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`. If you do decide to do this, make sure you have a login mapped to the user in SQL Server: {server_name}/Security/Logins. For a production server, this is the better way to go (I feel), as you are giving specific privileges to the app user.
3. Check the permissions in SQL Server. The permissions for the user connecting via the IIS App pool should look something like this:

[image: Membership settings for IIS APPPOOL user]

Let me know if any of the above helps, we can then proceed from there.

Comment: Have you tried step 2? I think having a proper user with sql authentication might put you on a better path. By the way, what you’re doing here is not recommended for a production server…you didn’t ask, but I wanted to point that out. If this was a staging server, then having the app and sql server on the same box might be appropriate. But for a production server, this is not an ideal setup.

Comment: Thanks, I started writing a comment earlier and realized I have not tried that, so I deleted the comment. I just went and did. Login fails for a user/pass in the connection string. I'm going to see if there are any clues I can find from that. Again when I use the same login and pass in SQL management studio it works. This is all on the production server.

Comment: But don’t you only encounter this issue when connecting to the database via the app? To me it does sound like an IIS issue with SQL Server. It might not be just an issue on production (Testing this fully using IIS on your local box might reveal that)

Comment: For reference, I like to run a full fat version on IIS on my local machine so that I can diagnose issues such as these. I find IIS Express to hide a lot of problems that might be later encountered in the deployed environment (my personal preference, however)

Comment: I only encounter this issue when the app is trying to connect to the database, yes. But I have 2 databases installed on the same server, one is mssqllocaldb, and the other is sqlexpress that I installed. And the app has no issue connecting to sqlexpress. I'm not saying it's not related to IIS, but since through the app I'm able to connect to one database successfully, I need to test a little more. Since the user/pass in connection string failed to log in, I'm now wondering if there are multiple versions of the mssqllocaldb that the server has and it's bringing up a different one or something.

Comment: I am working on the server directly right now, you might say I'm using it as a "local" machine when needed. The main difference between the server and my own machine is the operating system at this point. I'm debugging on the server. Going to write some code to try and access the EF database directly (as opposed to through the entity framework)

Comment: Good luck - it’s one of those tricky issues that requires a bit of time and patience. Let us know how you get on.