# Sql Server 2008 R2 Express LocalDB/ v11.0 connectivity issues

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I have a windows forms application which makes use of the local database (Service Database) "**.mdf**" file. I am able to connect to this database using the connection string below from the development machine.

```html
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DbConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MDFDb.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=30"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I am trying to publish the application now. When i attempt to install the application on a different machine. The application throws an error as shown below.

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at DataLayer.Common.DbOperations.GetDataSet(String CommandName, CommandType cmdType)
```

This error occurs only when i try to install in a different machine. I am not sure what I am missing?

Comment: Make sure that (SQL Server Browser service) is running and the required TCP ports are opened.

Comment: @Lolo I Thanks for ur reply. I found the Sql server Browser service is running and the TCP ports are open.

Comment: On the machine you are installing on?

Comment: Yes. It has all those up and running. I even tried restarting the machine too.

Comment: When i install it on development machine it works perfectly.

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20476608/issue-when-deploying-an-asp-net-mvc-localdb-application

Comment: Are you sure both named pipes and TCPIP enabled in the machine which you are trying to install?

Comment: @tarzanbappa  Yes. I have all 4 enabled.

Comment: Did you chechk whether your .mdf file is available or not in the deployed version?

Comment: @tarzanbappa Yes. I am able to see the .mdf file in that location.

Comment: Arrgh.. My bad. Version 11.0 is not under Sql Server 2008. Its 2012 . Thanks everyone I got it working.

Comment: Tarzanbappa, please post your answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

We have deployed a winforms app which allows the user to connect to either localdb / sql express, or a full version of sql server.  If the choose localdb we have been using this connection string:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName="C:\localdbfilename.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;
```

I hope that helps.  It has been working for us.