# steps to take website from local server to hosted server (going live)

Tags: django, web-publishing, publishing-site

I am very new to web development, and have a question in regards to taking your website "live."

I coded my site in python, using the Django framework. I have all my code stored in a local server, and want to move ahead with taking my web into production.

I've been looking online on any resources that provide a clear step-by-step instruction of going public with your site. However, they are either all unclear, extremely complicated, or based off "wordpress." I'm not using wordpress.

I understand the basic rules:

1. get a domain
2. get a web host
3. get a ftp
4. ??

my confusion is somewhere between 3. and 4. What happens after you get a FTP? Am I using GitHub at any point in this process? Are there special rules I have to follow (what do you do with your secret key in the settings.py?)

If you know of a great resource for beginner web developers who are trying to take their website live (and who are NOT using wordpress), I would truly appreciate your guidance.

thanks much!

Comment: This is a pretty complete tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7

Comment: As @ohrstrom pointed out, this is a good starting point (although a SQLite database is much easier to begin with). Once you've completed these steps, read this section of the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/) You'll need to check that your Django version corresponds to the docs that you're reading.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence yes SQLite is easier to set up, but the question was about *production*. Except for some special cases you should not use Django with SQLite backend in production. Following this logic you cold say as well "skipping nginx and just use ./manage.py runserver is easier to begin with"... :)

Comment: @ohrstrom I like your logic :) I personally use PostgreSQL, but I've read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913067/sqlite-as-a-production-database-for-a-low-traffic-site) and [here](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) that SQLite is suitable for production use. Didn't mean to overstep...

Comment: @KeenanLawrence :) so in these cases `runserver` should be fine as well. SQLite works with a global lock allowing only one thread/process can write at a time - if this is given, why don't combine it with (unthreaded) `runserver` :)

Comment: @ohrstrom Point conceded :)

Comment: thank you for the tutorial on digital ocean! very helpful!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of ftp or anything else

i used godaddy.com
i just brought a domain name then hosting space
no other thing i purchased

then i uploaded my files to website in sequence 
just thats it

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about a *Django* backed website??